# Missing extra plot with no error

Tags: r, shiny, plotly, r-plotly

I want to ceate a shiny app that gives heatmap of different aspects of data and when i click in the heatmap it gives one more graph that tells more about a particular company. I have created one but after the heatmap has been plotted when i click on the heatmap at a particular point the next graph is not plot nor is some error shown.

```
library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)
library(gplots)
ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel("Creating a database"),
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      textInput("name", "Company Name"),
      numericInput("income", "Income", value = 1),
      numericInput("expenditure", "Expenditure", value = 1),
      dateInput("date", h3("Date input"),value = Sys.Date() ,min = "0000-01-01",
                max = Sys.Date(), format = "dd/mm/yy"),
      actionButton("Action", "Submit"),#Submit Button
      actionButton("new", "New")),

    mainPanel(
      tabsetPanel(type = "tabs",
                  tabPanel("Table", tableOutput("table")),
                  tabPanel("Download",
                           textInput("filename", "Enter Filename for download"),   #filename
                           helpText(strong("Warning: Append if want to update existing data.")),
                           downloadButton('downloadData', 'Download'), #Button to save the file
                           downloadButton('Appenddata', 'Append')),#Button to update a file )
                  tabPanel("Plot", 
                           actionButton("filechoose", "Choose File"),
                           br(),
                           selectInput("toplot", "To Plot", choices =c("Income" = "inc1",
                                                                       "Expenditure" = "exp1",
                                                                       "Compare Income And 
                                                                       Expenditure" = "cmp1",
                                                                       "Gross Profit" = "gprofit1",
                                                                       "Net Profit" = "nprofit1",
                                                                       "Profit Lost" = "plost1",
                                                                       "Profit Percent" = "pp1",
                                                                       "Profit Trend" = "proftrend1"
                           )),
                           actionButton("plotit", "PLOT"),
                           plotOutput("Plot")),
                  tabPanel("Heatmap",
                           actionButton("combine","Combine"),
                           selectInput("ploth", "Plot Heatmap Of", choices =c("Income" = "inc1",
                                                                       "Expenditure" = "exp1",
                                                                       "Gross Profit" = "gprofit1",
                                                                       "Net Profit" = "nprofit1")),
                           actionButton("hplotit","Plot Heatmap"),
                           plotlyOutput("HeatPlot"),
                           textOutput("HAha"),
                           plotOutput("Next")
                           )
                  )
      )

    )
  )
# Define server logic required to draw a histogram
server <- function(input, output){
  #Global variable to save the data
  Data <- data.frame()
  Results <- reactive(data.frame(input$name, input$income, input$expenditure,
                                 as.character(input$date),
                                 as.character(Sys.Date())))

  #To append the row and display in the table when the submit button is clicked
  observeEvent(input$Action,{
    Data <<- rbind(Data,Results()) #Append the row in the dataframe
    output$table <- renderTable(Data) #Display the output in the table
  })

  observeEvent(input$new, {
    Data <<- NULL
    output$table <- renderTable(Data)
  })

  observeEvent(input$filechoose, {
    Data <<- read.csv(file.choose()) #Choose file to plot
    output$table <- renderTable(Data) #Display the choosen file details
  })

  output$downloadData <- downloadHandler(
    filename = function() {
      paste(input$filename , ".csv", sep="")}, # Create the download file name
    content = function(file) {
      write.csv(Data, file,row.names = FALSE) # download data
    })

  output$Appenddata <- downloadHandler(
    filename = function() {
      paste(input$filename, ".csv", sep="")}, 
    content = function(file) {
      write.table( Data, file=file.choose(),append = T, sep=',',
                   row.names = FALSE, col.names = FALSE) # Append data in existing
    })

  observeEvent(input$plotit, {
    inc <- c(Data[ ,2]) 
    exp <- c(Data[ ,3]) 
    date <- c(Data[,4])
    gprofit <- c(Data[ ,2]- Data[ ,3])
    nprofit <- c(gprofit - (gprofit*0.06))
    z <- as.numeric(nrow(Data))
    plost <- gprofit - nprofit
    pp <- (gprofit/inc) * 100
    proftrend <- c(gprofit[2:z]-gprofit[1:(z-1)])
    slope = c(((proftrend[2:(z-1)]-proftrend[1:(z-2)])/1),0)
    y = input$toplot
    switch(EXPR = y ,
           inc = output$Plot <- renderPlot(ggplot(data = Data, aes(x= Data[,4], y= inc))+
                                             geom_bar(stat = "identity",
                                                      fill = "blue")+xlab("Dates")+
                                             ylab("Income")+
                                             theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90))),
           exp = output$Plot <- renderPlot(ggplot(data = Data, aes(x= Data[,4], y= exp))+
                                             geom_bar(stat = "identity",
                                                      fill = "red")+xlab("Dates")+
                                             ylab("Expenditure")+
                                             theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90))),

           cmp = output$Plot <- renderPlot(ggplot(data = Data, aes(x= Data[,4]))+
                                             geom_line(aes(y= inc,group = 1, colour = "Income"))
                                           + geom_line(aes(y= exp,group =1, colour = "Expenditure"))+
                                             xlab("Dates")+ ylab("Income (in lakhs)")+
                                             scale_color_manual("",
                                                                breaks = c("Income","Expenditure"),
                                                                values = c(
                                                                  "Income"="green", "Expenditure"= "red"
                                                                ))+
                                             theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90))),

           gprofit = output$Plot <- renderPlot(ggplot(data = Data, aes(x= Data[,4], y= gprofit))+
                                                 geom_bar(stat = "identity",
                                                          fill = "blue")+xlab("Dates")+
                                                 ylab("Gross Profit (in lakhs)")+
                                                 theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90))),

           nprofit =  output$Plot <- renderPlot(ggplot(data = Data, aes(x= Data[,4], y= nprofit))
                                                +geom_bar(stat = "identity",
                                                          fill = "blue")+xlab("Dates")+
                                                  ylab("Net Profit (in lakhs)")+
                                                  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90))),

           plost =  output$Plot <- renderPlot(ggplot(data = Data, aes(x= Data[,4], y= plost))
                                              +geom_bar(stat = "identity",
                                                        fill = "blue")+xlab("Dates")+
                                                ylab("Profit Lost (in lakhs)")+
                                                theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90))),

           pp = output$Plot <- renderPlot(ggplot(data = Data, aes(x= Data[,4], y= pp))+
                                            geom_bar(stat = "identity",
                                                     fill = "blue")+xlab("Dates")+
                                            ylab("Profit Percentage")+
                                            theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90))),
           proftrend = output$Plot <- renderPlot(ggplot()+
                                                   geom_line(data = as.data.frame(date[2:z]),
                                                             aes(x= Data[c(2:z),4] , y= proftrend,
                                                                 group = 1, color = slope > 0))+
                                                   xlab("Dates")+ ylab("Profit Trend")+
                                                   theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90))
           ))})
  observeEvent(input$combine, {
    Data <<- cbind(read.csv(file.choose()),read.csv(file.choose()),read.csv(file.choose()),read.csv(file.choose()))
    output$table <- renderTable(Data)}) #Display the choosen file details

    observeEvent(input$hplotit, {
             inc1 <- as.data.frame(cbind(Dummy1 = Data[,2],Dummy2 = Data[,7],Dummy3 = Data[,12], Dummy4 = Data[,17]))
             inc1 <- as.matrix(inc1)
             exp1 <- as.data.frame(cbind(Dummy1 = Data[,3],Dummy2 = Data[,8],Dummy3 = Data[,13], Dummy4 = Data[,18]))
             exp1 <- as.matrix(exp1)
             gprofit1 <- as.data.frame(cbind(Dummy1 = Data[,3] - Data[,2],
                                            Dummy2 = Data[,8] - Data[,7],
                                            Dummy3 = Data[,13] - Data[,12],
                                            Dummy4 = Data[,18] - Data[,17]))
             gprofit1 <- as.matrix(gprofit1)
             nprofit1 <- as.data.frame(cbind(Dummy1 = (Data[,3] - Data[,2]) - ((Data[,3] - Data[,2]) * 0.06),
                                             Dummy2 = (Data[,8] - Data[,7]) - ((Data[,8] - Data[,7]) * 0.10),
                                             Dummy3 = (Data[,13] - Data[,12]) - ((Data[,13] - Data[,12]) * 0.18),
                                             Dummy4 = (Data[,18] - Data[,17]) - ((Data[,18] - Data[,17]) * 0.22)))
             nprofit1 <- as.matrix(nprofit1)
             date <- as.character(Data[,4])
             h = input$ploth
             switch(EXPR = h ,
                    inc1 = output$HeatPlot <- renderPlotly( plot_ly(x = colnames(inc1), y = date, z = inc1, type = "heatmap", colorscale = "Earth")),

                    exp1 = output$HeatPlot <- renderPlotly( plot_ly(x = colnames(exp1), y = date, z = exp1, type = "heatmap", colors = colorRamp(c("red", "yellow")))),

                    gprofit1 = output$HeatPlot <- renderPlotly( plot_ly(x = colnames(gprofit1), y = date, z = gprofit1, type = "heatmap", colorscale="Greys")),

                    nprofit1 = output$HeatPlot <- renderPlotly( plot_ly(x = colnames(nprofit1), y = date, z = nprofit1, type = "heatmap")) 
                    )

    })

    output$HAha <- renderText({
      event_data(event = "plotly_click", source = "heatplot")
    })

    output$Next <- renderPlot({
d <- event_data(event = "plotly_click", source = "heatplot")
vars <- c(d[["x"]])
if(is.null(d))return(NULL)
else 
  switch(EXPR = vars, 
         Dummy1 = plot(x = Data[,4], y = inc1$vars),
         Dummy2 = plot(x = Data[,4], y = exp1$vars),
         Dummy3 = plot(x = Data[,4], y = gprofit1$vars),
         Dummy4 = plot(x = Data[,4], y = nprofit1$vars)
         )})
}

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

What i want is that after a heatmap like

[image]

has been plotted when i click on any one cell, a further line chart is plotted depending on values from that particular selected column.
What is it that i am missing? PLease Help. Data is a set of 4 csv files so cannot be put over here. Sorry.

The main code parts that matter are

```
ui.server

 tabPanel("Plot", 
                       actionButton("filechoose", "Choose File"),
                       br(),
                       selectInput("toplot", "To Plot", choices =c("Income" = "inc1",
                                                                   "Expenditure" = "exp1",
                                                                   "Compare Income And 
                                                                   Expenditure" = "cmp1",
                                                                   "Gross Profit" = "gprofit1",
                                                                   "Net Profit" = "nprofit1",
                                                                   "Profit Lost" = "plost1",
                                                                   "Profit Percent" = "pp1",
                                                                   "Profit Trend" = "proftrend1"
                       )),
                       actionButton("plotit", "PLOT"),
                       plotOutput("Plot")),
              tabPanel("Heatmap",
                       actionButton("combine","Combine"),
                       selectInput("ploth", "Plot Heatmap Of", choices =c("Income" = "inc1",
                                                                          "Expenditure" = "exp1",
                                                                          "Gross Profit" = "gprofit1",
                                                                          "Net Profit" = "nprofit1")),
                       actionButton("hplotit","Plot Heatmap"),
                       plotlyOutput("HeatPlot"),
                       plotlyOutput("Next")

shiny.server

observeEvent(input$hplotit, {
    inc1 <- as.data.frame(cbind(Dummy1 = Data[,2],Dummy2 = Data[,7],Dummy3 = Data[,12], Dummy4 = Data[,17]))
    inc1 <- as.matrix(inc1)
    exp1 <- as.data.frame(cbind(Dummy1 = Data[,3],Dummy2 = Data[,8],Dummy3 = Data[,13], Dummy4 = Data[,18]))
    exp1 <- as.matrix(exp1)
    gprofit1 <- as.data.frame(cbind(Dummy1 = Data[,3] - Data[,2],
                                    Dummy2 = Data[,8] - Data[,7],
                                    Dummy3 = Data[,13] - Data[,12],
                                    Dummy4 = Data[,18] - Data[,17]))
    gprofit1 <- as.matrix(gprofit1)
    nprofit1 <- as.data.frame(cbind(Dummy1 = (Data[,3] - Data[,2]) - ((Data[,3] - Data[,2]) * 0.06),
                                    Dummy2 = (Data[,8] - Data[,7]) - ((Data[,8] - Data[,7]) * 0.10),
                                    Dummy3 = (Data[,13] - Data[,12]) - ((Data[,13] - Data[,12]) * 0.18),
                                    Dummy4 = (Data[,18] - Data[,17]) - ((Data[,18] - Data[,17]) * 0.22)))
    nprofit1 <- as.matrix(nprofit1)
    date <- as.character(Data[,4])
    h = input$ploth
    switch(EXPR = h ,
           inc1 = output$HeatPlot <- renderPlotly( plot_ly(x = colnames(inc1), y = date, z = inc1, type = "heatmap", colorscale = "Earth")),

           exp1 = output$HeatPlot <- renderPlotly( plot_ly(x = colnames(exp1), y = date, z = exp1, type = "heatmap", colors = colorRamp(c("red", "yellow")))),

           gprofit1 = output$HeatPlot <- renderPlotly( plot_ly(x = colnames(gprofit1), y = date, z = gprofit1, type = "heatmap", colorscale="Greys")),

           nprofit1 = output$HeatPlot <- renderPlotly( plot_ly(x = colnames(nprofit1), y = date, z = nprofit1, type = "heatmap")) 
    )

  })
output$HAha <- renderText({
      event_data(event = "plotly_click", source = "heatplot")
    })

    output$Next <- renderPlot({
d <- event_data(event = "plotly_click", source = "heatplot")
vars <- c(d[["x"]])
if(is.null(d))return(NULL)
else 
  switch(EXPR = vars, 
         Dummy1 = plot(x = Data[,4], y = inc1$vars),
         Dummy2 = plot(x = Data[,4], y = exp1$vars),
         Dummy3 = plot(x = Data[,4], y = gprofit1$vars),
         Dummy4 = plot(x = Data[,4], y = nprofit1$vars)
         )})


    }
        })
```

The ploth is in both places so that the computer knows if dummyy1 is selected then it has to plot income only. Dont have to give two selected inputs for both.

Comment: I think you have conflicting `id` as you can have only unique ones on HTML page, check your `output$...` and `input$...` so they are all unique

Comment: So what do i do if i want input at one place to give its output to two separate places to do two different things? @PorkChop